# ETH sent to an address that was generated for contracts, how can I recover?

Tags: ethereumjs, cryptography, ethereumjs-tx

I have transferred money to an ethereum address that belongs to the smart contracts.

```
const priv = "0x" + crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex");
const pub = "0x" + util.generateAddress(util.toBuffer(priv), util.toBuffer(parseInt(req.params.nonce))).toString("hex");
```

This is how I generated the private key and public address. I have a track of the nonce but when I try to import this private key in trust wallet, I cannot see any funds there.

Crazy thing is that I found out now that the `generateAddress` expects the first parameter to be a smart contract address, whereas I provided a private key and it still accepted it. An error here would have saved me from losing 2000$.

Is there any way to recover this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's `util`? If you don't have the private keys for that address you will not be able to access its funds.

Comment: What happens if you generate a tx using that private key? If you have not done this before _BE VERY CAREFUL_ with how you do it, you can lose all of your funds if you use it wrong.

Comment: Provide the TXID of the transaction please.